# Debian ssh connection refused

Tags: linux, networking, ssh, debian

I'm running an old HP ProLiant DL360p gen8 server for home automation. Mostly node-red, mysql and a grafana instance for charting. After about a year of operation, today I was unable to ssh using MobaXTerm and am greeted by a "Remote side unexpectedly closed network connection" message.
Trying to ssh from Windows PowerShell I get a

```
Unable to negotiate with 192.168.100.13 port 22: no matching key exchange method found. Their offer: diffie-hellman-group1-sha1
```

I ended up on [this](https://www.infosecmatter.com/solution-for-ssh-unable-to-negotiate-errors/) site explaining a possible solution and came up with this.

```
ssh -oKexAlgorithms=+diffie-hellman-group1-sha1 -oHostKeyAlgorithms=+ssh-dss -c aes256-cbc user@192.168.100.13
```

which at least asks me for a password, but then gives me a

```
Connection to 192.168.100.13 closed by remote host.
Connection to 192.168.100.13 closed.
```

The first time I tried this i got something similar to this (copied from a DigitalOcean thread)

```
@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@
@    WARNING: REMOTE HOST IDENTIFICATION HAS CHANGED!     @
@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@
IT IS POSSIBLE THAT SOMEONE IS DOING SOMETHING NASTY!
Someone could be eavesdropping on you right now (man-in-the-middle attack)!
It is also possible that a host key has just been changed.
The fingerprint for the RSA key sent by the remote host is
51:82:00:1c:7e:6f:ac:ac:de:f1:53:08:1c:7d:55:68.
Please contact your system administrator.
Add correct host key in /Users/isaacalves/.ssh/known_hosts to get rid of this message.
Offending RSA key in /Users/isaacalves/.ssh/known_hosts:12
RSA host key for 104.131.16.158 has changed and you have requested strict checking.
Host key verification failed.
```

The weird thing is that none of my services (node-red, mysql, grafana) are responding.

Did a

```
apt-get update
```

followed by an

```
apt-get upgrade
```

thinking I needed to update the system. No change.
Did I just get hacked? :))

Comment: Are you sure you have only one device with that IP address? (Use arping or tcpdump -e to check.) It sounds a lot like you're actually ssh'ing to some old NAS or even a wifi router and not to your server.

Comment: Advanced IP Scanner shows only one device with that IP address and the MAC address matches the server.

Comment: Advanced IP Scanner _always_ shows only one device with that IP address. (As most IP scanners do.) It's the wrong tool for this purpose.

Comment: @CatalinPop Check your router's DHCP assignments via the router's WebAdmin or SSH _(or the machine serving as the DHCP/DNS server)_,

Answer (score 1):

I ended up changing the static IP of my server and that fixed the problem.
Now all I have to do is find the impersonating device.
As user1686 mentioned, it seems to be an old NAS or wifi router.